# React app not showing in Codepen no matter what?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I have a react app that I made in VS Studio, putting it into codepen, it doesnt seem to load a thing, any suggestions?

I have tried making sure React is linked and checked all of my syntax, no errors on local host but no display in codepen.

I have looked through the code multiple times and I feel its such a silly mistake

https://codepen.io/donnieberry97/pen/EzmOvW

```
    class TodoListt extends React.Component {
      state = {};

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          userInput: "",
          list: [],
          editing: false,
        };
      }

      changeUserInput(input) {
        this.setState({
          userInput: input
        })
      }


      addToList() {
        if (this.state.userInput === "") { (alert("Please enter a To-do")); return; };
        const { list, userInput } = this.state;
        this.setState({
          list: [...list, {
            text: userInput, key: Date.now(), done: false
          }],
          userInput: ''
        })
      }

      handleChecked(e, index) {
        console.log(e.target.checked);
        const list = [...this.state.list];
        list[index] = { ...list[index] };
        list[index].done = e.target.checked;
        this.setState({
          list
        })
      }

      handleEditing(e) {
        this.setState({
          editing: true
        })
      }

      handleRemoved(index) {
        const list = [...this.state.list];
        list.splice(index, 1);

        this.setState({
          list
        })
      }

      render() {

        var viewStyle = {};
        var editStyle = {};

        if (this.state.editing) {
          viewStyle.display = "none"
        }
        else {
          editStyle.display = "none"
        }


        return (
          <div className="to-do-list-main">
            <input
              onChange={(e) => this.changeUserInput(e.target.value)}
              value={this.state.userInput}
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="submitButton">
              <button onClick={() => { this.addToList(this.state.userInput) }}>Add todo</button>
            </div>

            {this.state.list.map((list, index) => (
              <div className="form">
                <ul>
                  {/* <div style={viewStyle} onDoubleClick={this.handleEditing.bind(t his)}> */}

                  <li key={list.key}>
                    <div class="liFlexCheck">
                      <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleChecked(e, index)} />
                    </div>
                    <div class="liFlexText">
                      <div class="liFlexTextContainer">
                        <span style={{ textDecoration: list.done ? 'line-through' : 'inherit' }}>
                          {list.text}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={(index) => this.handleRemoved(index)}>Remove</button>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      style={editStyle}
                      value={list.text}
                    />
                  </li>
                  {/* </div> */}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ))}


          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `import` statements, working [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvmxvM).

You shouldn't use `import` when you got **External Scripts**.

Also, you got many errors in your code that should be handled, like:

- `<div class="submitButton">`, use `className`.
- Each child in a list should have a unique `key` prop.
- Form field with `value` prop but without `onChange` handler.

Check out the logs:

[image: Edit Todolist]

Answer (score 1):

In codpen, you don't need to import the `react` instead just write code,
here is codepen working one : [codepen](https://codepen.io/vishnuprasadkv55/pen/dEWwYw)

from codesandbox, you can learn with all imports also because it doesn't uses any external scripts,
your code will work fine if you add an import to it
that is `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`
codesandbox will show all these suggestions,
here is codesandbox working example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6emmu)